# How to convert into a movie a series of images that were originally from a movie

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have a set of jpg images. These images were originally taken from a movie. It was in C++ something like (I am explaining how I got these images for reference. This is not the main part of the question)

```
cv::Mat test_image;

cv::VideoCapture video_capture;
video_capture.open(test_video_name);
while(true){
  video_capture >> test_image;
  if (test_image.empty()) break;
  std::string input_file_name=get_file_name();
  cv::imwrite(input_file_name,test_image);
  }
```

Anyway, I got these images and I want to convert them back into a movie using Python

so I do

```
import cv2 as cv
import glob

glob_arg= image_folder+"/*.jpg"

size=getSize()
out = cv.VideoWriter(output_video,cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 10, size)
for filename in sorted(glob.glob(glob_arg)):
    img = cv.imread(filename)
    print(filename)
    out.write(img)

out.release()
```

Now, my problem is in the `VideoWriter` problem, specifically the "10" parameter. How can I know what value to put there? This parameter is the number of frames per second. How can I determine it so as to have the same or similar movie as the original one?

Comment: Do you know the movie length and total number of images? If not, I would suggest starting with `25` since that is a very common frame rate.

Answer (score 1):

In your C++ code, you can add this line under `video_capture.open(test_video_name);` to get the FPS of the video:

```
double fps = video_capture.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS);
std::cout << fps << std::endl;
```

Comment: mmm. `CAP_PROP_FPS was not declared in this scope`.... so it had to be `cv::CAP_PROP_FPS` and also `video_capture`

Comment: @KansaiRobot Whoops! My mistake. Did the corrected version work for you?

Comment: It extracted the fps. I am going to apply it to the reconstruction in python in a few days. I ll let you know.

Comment: I tried this approach (which theoretically makes sense) but unless I made a mistake, it didn't work as expected :( I extracted the fps but when I applied it to the python script it generated a too fast video